# Is it possible to set an alarm in a certain time (i.e at 8 am) and it will continue keep alarming for a specific time (i.e for 1 hour)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3

I like to get an alarm at some specific time (for example at 8.0 am) and i like to continue it for 1 hour. so it will stop at 9.0 am. I also like it to keep alarming me after 5 or 10 mins. But after 9.0 am it will stop alarming me.

Again it will continue the very next day at 8.0 am. Is it possible to do with local notification or any other way.
TIA

Comment: If it were not possible, how can that exist: https://www.google.de/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=alarm+app+ios&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=srQ-WeTbFKuk8wee0rqoBg What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have tried with local notification which can be start but can not be stopped. Also it was not possible to trigger the notification again for the next day. I have no idea which way to go to solve this problem.

Comment: An alarm is only possible by the os but you can run a notification with a sound you know the length of is that case you know when to schedule the next notification if the user did interrupt the alarm then you can cancel all of the notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to run the code for certain amount of time in background mode. The alarm thing can be done only by apple OS.

But it is possible to get notified for certain amount of time for example get notify for 1 hour by creating multiple notification for that particular one hour and make trigger at that time. Though it is not perfect solution.